# What is the best way to filter URLs for input?

Tags: url, input, filter, parsing, xss

I have a form that is accepting URLs from users in PHP.

What characters should I allow or disallow? Currently I use

$input= preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\?:#.()\,/\&\'\\"]/", "", $string);

$input=substr($input,0,255);

So, it's trimmed to 255 chars and only can include letters, numbers, and ? - _ : # ( ) , & ' " /

Anything I should be stripping that I'm not, or anything I'm stripping that might need to be in a valid URL?

Comment: I should mention, I also use trim() and strip_tags().

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to handle security and avoid XSS with user entered URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205923/best-way-to-handle-security-and-avoid-xss-with-user-entered-urls)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) which defines the URL specification states that only the characters

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789+.-
```

may be used within a URL scheme, and only the characters

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789$-_.+!*'(),;/?:@=&
```

may be used unencoded within the scheme-specific part of a URL. (`;/?:@=&`, if used unencoded, must be used for their "reserved purposes", but if you're just checking for invalid characters you don't need to worry about that). So if you want full generality, I'd check the URL against this regex:

```
"/([a-zA-Z+.-]+:\/\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9\$\-_\.\+\!\*'\(\),\;\/\?\:\@\=\&]+)/"
```

(probably some of that escaping is not necessary). If you're only looking for HTTP URLs, (some of) the other answers should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow = sign and % for things like %20.  Also the @ sign is legal

You can validate the url with a regex like this

```
/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
```

Also i don't think parens and quotes are allowed in urls either.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you parse the URI according to the specs (being somewhat lenient about illegal characters) and then rebuilding it strictly according to the specs... Which sounds like a lot but I've got a headstart with a class I wrote and use for my own projects.

[I have put it on pastebin, because it is rather large.](http://pastebin.com/f2b07e589)

Example:

```
$uri = new N_Uri('http://example.com/path/segments/with spaces?key=value');
echo $uri;
```

Prints out: http://example.com/path/segments/with%20spaces?key=value

Comment: Can you repaste it with "forever" checked?  Or, host yourself.  =]

Comment: @jimmy: Your welcome! Be warned that it does not parse everything perfectly (ie. you can't dump all arbitrary binary data into it) but it will output again into a valid URI. It has parsed every bastardization of a URI I have ever thrown at it without a problem. I just hope the docs are up to date...

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex I used on a TinyUrl clone site I made:

```
([a-zA-Z]+://)?([a-z0-9A-Z-]+\.[a-z0-9A-Z\.-]+[a-z0-9A-Z/_?=;%&,+\.\-]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there's input type="url", it can be used for simpler applications and maybe complex ones too.