# Sanitize $_GET parameters to avoid XSS and other attacks

Tags: php, sanitization

I have a website in php that does include() to embed the content into a template. The page to load is given in a get parameter, I add ".php" to the end of the parameter and include that page. I need to do some security check to avoid XSS or other stuff (not mysql injection since we do not have a database). What I've come up with is the following.

```
$page = $_GET['page'];

if(!strpos(strtolower($page), 'http') || !strpos($page, '/') ||
    !strpos($page, '\\') || !strpos($page, '..')) {
        //append ".php" to $page and include the page
```

Is there any other thing I can do to furtherly sanitize my input?

Comment: Don't check the result of strpos() like that - it will return zero if the match is at the start of the string, which will evaluate to false

Comment: @Tom, the acceppted solution lets me avoid that too, anyway thanks, I'll remember your advice for future code.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15825812/59087

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$page = preg_replace('/[^-a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $_GET['page']);
```

Is probably the quickest way to sanitize this, this will take anything and make sure that it only contains letters, numbers, underscores or dashes.

Comment: still can attack using hex code: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection/12202218#12202218 and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/12710285#12710285

Comment: both links are about mysql and this question is not about sql injection

Answer (score 7):

Don't "sanitize" - Attacks are specific to the use of data, not the source. Escape values as you output them instead. See also my answer to [What’s the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php/130323#130323)

Comment: I read it, but I don't think that fits the website I'm working on.

Answer (score 5):

Define an explicit list of pages you have in your source code and then use it to check the input. Yes, it's more work, but it makes it very clear what is allowed and what is not. For example:

```
$AVAILABLE_PAGES = array('home', 'news',  ...);
$AVAILABLE_PAGES = array_fill_keys($AVAILABLE_PAGES, 1);

$page = $_GET['page'];
if (!$AVAILABLE_PAGES[$page]) {
   header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
   die('Page not found.');
}

include "pages/$page.php";
```