# How to avoid XSS Attack or Sanitize the $_GET's KEY parameter via PHP

Tags: php, get, xss

I just tested a link below, will have XXS attack on IE11.

```
http://example.net/test/?"*alert(1)*"
```

I had find many of the way to sanitize the url parameter.
Mostly all the solution is sanitize $_GET's value instead of $_GET's key like this url
[Sanitize $_GET parameters to avoid XSS and other attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587695/sanitize-get-parameters-to-avoid-xss-and-other-attacks)

But above's url i provide when i print_r my $_GET is `Array ( ["*alert(1)*"] => )`

So can i know how to avoid this kind of attack ? They attack using $_GET's key instead of value.

Thanks lot.

Comment: There are various ways to do this, but i would suggest reading up on PHP filter_var http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php. It provides an easy way to do exactly what your after

Comment: It has nothing to do with key or value.  Comes down to you echoing out unsanitized HTML.  See reading above, maybe some time on OWASP site too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

founded my solution, I need rewrite HTACESS to redirect from http call to https. so that in https environment it will prevent xss attack when they type in their url.

Answer (score 1):

XSS attacks occurs when printing malicious code but the code should be executable according to HTML and JavaScript rules. for instance, printing `*alert(1)*` will not issue any alert (will not be executed) if its not properly written. however,

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

and

```
<div onclick="alert(1);"...>
```

Will be executed.

For more detail you can see  [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)