# .htaccess that redirects to index.html, or to index.php if there are parameters

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking for a `.htaccess` that does the following:

1. For users that visit `mydomain.com`, the server should return the `index.html` file from the root.
2. For users that visit `mydomain.com/something/`, `mydomain.com/anything/123/`, `mydomain.com/some%20encoded%20text`, etc., the server should return the `index.php` file from the root and pass the text after `www.mydomain.com/` as a PHP `$_GET` variable.

I tried the WordPress `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

But this redirects everything to the `index.php` file.

Comment: Why not just direct all traffic to index.php and if there is no additional URI passed, just serve up the index.html content?  Seems odd to have a front controller for all pages in a site except for one.

Comment: @MikeBrant I expect most traffic to come to mydomain.com directly, so I'm thinking serving a static html file is better than serving a php.

Comment: I added the solution that was initially attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?f=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Inside `index.php` you can access `$_GET['f']` variable that will give you requested URI.

Comment: Thank you, works great. What PHP sanitization method would you recommend in this case for the $_GET['f'], just to prevent malicious code? (I will be using the variable as a plain string to calculate a hash for it)

Comment: You're welcome. See this question for sanitization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205923/best-way-to-handle-security-and-avoid-xss-with-user-entered-urls

Comment: It seems that it does not work if the encoded url contains a new line character, such as _http://mydomain.com/one%0Atwo_ I get _ERROR 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND_

Comment: To use encoded characters: `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?f=$1 [L,QSA,B,NE]`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with the new line character %0A, I still get the 404 Error.

Comment: `.+` should match anything. It shouldn't cause 404

Comment: The problem was with the _$_ at the end. If I only use ^(.+), it works and I no longer get the error, however I no longer get the whole text in php using $_GET, only the first line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40743/discussion-between-jamrelian-and-anubhava)