# Best URL Encoding technique in c#

Tags: c#, url-encoding

I have a href which gets filled in by reading a property from a database like this

```
  lblName.HRef = user.PublicSiteUrl;
```

I want to safely encode this URL to protect against any persisted XSS attack.

Which encoding should be useful for this without causing any issues with the URL structure?

For example, if I have this URL coming from the database `https://google.com?q=<SCRIPT>alert(“Cookie”+document.cookie)</SCRIPT>` ..How Do i make this URL safe so the script is not executed as part of URL

Answer (score 0):

Why not [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://Test/k=<script>alert("hacked")</script>"));  This does not work.

Comment: @user3637345 If you had a test scenario that you wanted tested, why didn't you add it to your question to begin with?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a scenraio as such. I just wanted to see if there is built in class for something that prevents any XSS attack.

Comment: @user3637345 how would you expect something to actually keep the url in tact?  If a threat is detected, shouldn't the request be blocked entirely?

Comment: have an example added in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [Uri.EscapeUriString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
https://server/test.aspx?<SCRIPT>alert(“Cookie”+document.cookie)</SCRIPT>
```

Will become:

```
https://server/test.aspx?%3CSCRIPT%3Ealert(%E2%80%9CCookie%E2%80%9D+document.cookie)%3C/SCRIPT%3E
```

Comment: This works for me..Do you know if there can be XSS attacks that bypass this encoding.

Comment: This should prevent tags from getting inserted, but I suppose you would still have problems if someone entered `javascript:alert('hi')`. Perhaps you could also check that the url starts with http:// or https://. Also, this post has some good info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205923/best-way-to-handle-security-and-avoid-xss-with-user-entered-urls