# How to xss sanitize a url in python

Tags: python, xss

There's tons of discussion on this topic on the web.  Lots of references saying "you must sanitize urls".

Even Jeff Atwood has an answer for the topic: [Best way to handle security and avoid XSS with user entered URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205923/best-way-to-handle-security-and-avoid-xss-with-user-entered-urls/205967#205967) This answer must be disregarded because there are comments pointing out that it is wrong, but no response to those comments - so this is not a duplicate question.

But nowhere can I find a straight answer to the question "how, specifically, do I sanitize a URL in Python?", with an example.

Comment: How are you displaying a user-provided URL?

Comment: @blender in a web browser, but that shouldn't matter in answering this question.  I'm interested in knowing how to do it in Python.

Comment: By "how", I mean how are you putting the URL in your page? As a link? As an image? Or are you allowing the user to input HTML?

Comment: I am sanitzing urls provided by end users which will then become hrefs in anchor tags.

Comment: @DukeDougal Shockingly, this is still the case 8 years later