# How to sanitize url string in Python?

Tags: python, url, sanitize

I have a python app that works with URL lists and produces bash script as an output.

How to sanitize URL so that a malicious user could not inject bash commands that will be executed on my infrastructure.

For instance:

```
http://www.circl.lu/a.php?rm -Rf /etc
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205923/best-way-to-handle-security-and-avoid-xss-with-user-entered-urls/205967#205967 ?

Comment: Also: https://code.google.com/archive/p/owasp-esapi-python

Comment: Whether or not you *need* to sanitize it depends on what you are doing with it. As a simple example, `printf '%s\n' "$UNSANITIZED_URL"` is completely safe. (Assuming no buffer-overflow bugs or the like in your shell itself.)

Comment: @DirtyBit the bash script is output, I need to sanitize URL in Python

Comment: @chepner the output (bash script) may be executed on different systems, so I have no control over it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess `urllib` is an option to parse the urls, in order to escape harmful characters. At least it looks like a good resource for your use case. See the docs of [url-quoting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting).

```
from urllib.parse import quote

quote('touch foo', safe='/')
quote('rm -Rf /etc', safe='/')
quote('http://www.circl.lu/a.php?rm -Rf /etc', safe='/:?&')

#'touch%20foo'
#'rm%20-Rf%20/etc'
#'http://www.circl.lu/a.php?rm%20-Rf%20/etc'
```