# Are bad urls considered XSS?

Tags: security, url, xss

I have a website where any user can enter an url to an other website/domain.
Is this considered a threat (in XSS)? (since users can enter malicious urls to scripts/sites/...)

Is it possible to prevent this?

Comment: Are you presenting those URLs as clickable links in your application?

Comment: Yes, they are clickable for users

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205923/best-way-to-handle-security-and-avoid-xss-with-user-entered-urls).