# How to check if a URL is a XSS risk and sanitize it so that it is not

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xss

One of the first rules of security is to never trust user data.  However it is not uncommon that a website needs to allow a visitor to key in a url and that url needs to be used on an href of an anchor tag.  I have such a situation and I have no control over what the visitor may submit for the url.

I need to be able to tell if the url submitted is a Cross Site Scripting (XSS) risk and if so not allow it's use in an href.  Or alternatively, if the url is a XSS risk, then if there is some way to clean the url or render it safe for use in an href of a anchor tag, that'd be preferable.

I have done quite a bit of research on the topic and am aware of [Best way to handle security and avoid XSS with user entered URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205923/best-way-to-handle-security-and-avoid-xss-with-user-entered-urls) and [Should I sanitize HTML markup for a hosted CMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176195/should-i-sanitize-html-markup-for-a-hosted-cms) here on SO but neither provide clear modern guidance.  I have seen there and elsewhere references to http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-dotnet/ but it's unclear if this library is current and even more unclear how to use it to do what I am asking.

The https://code.google.com/archive/p/owasp-esapi-dotnet/ page for example claims that the API docs for the owasap esapi dot net library are here: https://alexsmolen.com/dotnetesapidoc/index.html but the page returns an error about a missing key.  Not something that instills confidence or provides info about the APIs available.  Hmm.  This page https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_.NET_Project appears to be docs for OWASP related to .net but nowhere on the page does it mentions the esapi library.

How can I evaluate whether a given url is a XSS vulnerability and if it is a XSS vlnerability how can I clean it and use it safely in an href of a html anchor tag?

Comment: This page contains the url to the NuGet package https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_AntiXSS_Library being https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS/.

Comment: Seems there is also some out-of-the-box anti-XSS support from the .NET framework itself https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-be/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder?view=netframework-4.7.1 I don't have experience with either (yet).